# Is it normal for principle components to have the same SD?

Tags: r, pca, standard-deviation

I'm trying to determine outliers of a PCA by calculating the sd of the eigenvectors - however it returns the sd as equal for each PC.

1) Is this normal and 
2) Is this the right approach for calculating the sd of a PCA? Should I be using the eigenvalue instead?

I have attempted a few different means of calculating the SD and they each return the same

```
## calculate PCA sd and determine outliers 
library("matrixStats")
PCA<-as.matrix(read.table(file = "pca.eigenvec", head = T))
SD<-rep(NA,10)
for (i in c(1:10)){
  SD[i]<-sd(PCA[,i+2])
}
test<-apply(X=PCA[,c(3:12)], MARGIN = 2, FUN=sd)
test1<-colSds(PCA[,c(3:12)])
```

Comment: PCA is typically normalized. You would want to use the eigenvalue instead to give a sense of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the outlieres in your PCA you have to use the scores not the eigenvectors. Eigenvectors are just giving the direction of the the PC-Axes and it makes absolut no sense to calculate their sd.